# Finding and fixing label islands in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph where each node has an integer label. If the graph is well-behaved, labeled regions will be continuous. I'd like to write something in python networkx to "fix" bad graphs. For example, in

[image]

I'd like to:

1) identify bad nodes (the ones in dotted blue lines); then

2) remove their label and "fill" with the correct value

My graph vocabulary is weak; are there networkx functions that can do this?

Note: not sure if it makes a difference, but and all nodes have a degree of 3, and the graph is always a topological sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For each label, make a subgraph of your original graph containing all nodes with that label (`networkx.subgraph`).

2) For each subgraph, find the connected components with `networkx.connected_components`, which returns a generator of node sets, one for each component.

3) For each component that is not the largest component of its class, find the neighbours of each node with `networkx.neighbors`; determine their labels and assign the most common label (that is not also the label of the component) to the nodes in that component.

This procedure may fail if large mislabeled "islands" are adjacent to each other but should work for the example shown.

Comment: I wonder if could work around your caveat by doing an initial pass to knock out bad labels, then a second pass reassign based on neighbours. What if the example is scaled up though, so the "islands" have interior nodes that don't have good neighbours?

Comment: Oh actually, scratch that - I think I misunderstood 3). I thought it was a per-node operation, which was where my question in the previous comment came from.